# Split mysql column in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a table, called mess_stock. mess_stock table has following values,

```
sno    pay_amount   pay_type
1       10           1
2       60           1
2       500          2
```

I want to sum the payment by its payment type and wants to rename it as mess_pay if pay_type is 1, est_pay if pay_type is 2.

I have tried the following query

```
select pay_amount,sum(if(pay_type=1, pay_amount, 0)) mess_pay, sum(if(pay_type=2, pay_amount, 0)) est_pay from mess_stock group by pay_type;
```

this will gives as the following value

```
+------------+----------+---------+
| pay_amount | mess_pay | est_pay |
+------------+----------+---------+
|      10.00 |    70.00 |    0.00 |
|     500.00 |     0.00 |  500.00 |
+------------+----------+---------+
```

But I need answer like this

```
+----------+---------+
| mess_pay | est_pay |
+----------+---------+
|    70.00 |  500.00 |
+----------+---------+
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
SELECT SUM(IF(pay_type = 1, pay_amount, 0)) mess_pay, SUM(IF(pay_type=2, pay_amount, 0)) est_pay 
FROM mess_stock;
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: it said   ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

Comment: this works fine  SELECT SUM(IF(pay_type = 1, pay_amount, 0)) mess_pay, SUM(IF(pay_type=2, pay_amount, 0)) est_pay  FROM mess_stock;