# Mysql query sum query in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

[Split mysql column in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669315/split-mysql-column-in-codeigniter)

the above link is one of my question. I got the answer for the above question. But now I have a sql query as follows,

```
SELECT SUM(IF(pay_type = 1, `pay_amount`, `0))` mess_pay, SUM(IF(pay_type=2, `pay_amount`, `0))` est_pay FROM (`mess_stock`);
```

I want to use above code in codeigniter.

I have tried the following method

```
$this->db->select('SUM(IF(pay_type = 1, pay_amount, 0)) mess_pay, SUM(IF(pay_type=2, pay_amount, 0)) est_pay');
$this->db->from('mess_stock');
```

But it throws the following output

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mess_pay, SUM(IF(pay_type=2, `pay_amount`, `0))` est_pay FROM (`mess_stock`)' at line 1


SELECT SUM(IF(pay_type = 1, `pay_amount`, `0))` mess_pay, SUM(IF(pay_type=2, `pay_amount`, `0))` est_pay FROM (`mess_stock`)


Filename: /var/www/college/modules/mess_fees/models/mess_fees_model.php
Line Number: 25
```

How can I execute the above query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the last parameter of `select()` to false :

```
$this->db->select('SUM(IF(pay_type = 1, pay_amount, 0)) mess_pay, SUM(IF(pay_type=2, pay_amount, 0)) est_pay', false);
```

It will prevent CI from adding ``.

Take a look at the doc : http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select

> $this->db->select() accepts an optional second parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks. This is useful if you need a compound select statement.

Comment: It is showing 8 minutes to accept, that's why still I am not accepting the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

USE THIS

```
$summ = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(column) FROM 
table WHERE columnid > '0' ")->result_array();
echo '<br>summ=>'.$summ[0]['SUM(answer)'];
```